# Is it possible to declare methods via template in c++?

Tags: c++

My intention is to refrain from macros style when I need to define a lot of similar methods. So I'm interested, can I use templates or anything like that?

This is the general idea in pseudo-c++:

```
template <class T, class U> void myMethod(T t, U u){ ..do a lot .. }

class A {
public:
  A(){}
  void myMethod<int, int>;
  void myMethod<float, char>;

  // ... etc
};
```

Comment: Awwwww - what's wrong with macros ;)?  Anyway - check out this link: http://www.boostpro.com/mplbook/

Comment: I'm not sure what you want this code to do...

Comment: Don't go through a lot of contortions to avoid "evil" constructs.  Macros and even goto have their place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
template <class T, class U> class A 
{
public:
    void MemberSet( T t, U u );
};
```

ADDED:

```
#include <typeinfo>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
class A 
{
public:
    template <class T, class U> void MemberSet( T t, U u ) {
        cout << typeid(t).name() << " " << typeid(u).name() << endl;
    };
};

int main() 
{
    A a;
    a.MemberSet(5,5);
    a.MemberSet<char, long>(5,5);
}
```

you may want to explicitly instantiate

```
template void A::MemberSet<int, long> (int, long);
```

Comment: That creates a bunch of class `A`, not a single class `A` with a bunch of methods.

Comment: yep i need to create a bunch of overloaded methods

Comment: @DmitryKachko: is my solution suits for your task?

Comment: In fact Im thinking about something that can use overloading method  without direct type definition, so that caller does not care about argument type, but you are making me reconsider the whole thing, why not..

Comment: if i understand you right, no need in direct type definition, types may be deduced, i edited.

Answer (score 2):

No, but you can use inheritance.

```
template <class derived_T, class T, class U>
struct base {
  void myMethod_(T t, U u) { 
    // use this to access derived class members:
    static_cast<derived_T*>(this)->
  }
};

struct a : base<a, int, int>, base<a, float, float> {
  template <class T, class U>
  void myMethod(T&& t, U&& u) {
    base<a,T,U>::myMethod_(std::forward<T>(t), std::forward<U>(u));
  }
};
```

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Should be fixed now

Answer (score 1):

No, but you can:

```
template <class T, class U> void struct myMethodWrapper
{
    void myMethod(T t, U u){ ..do a lot .. }
};
```

And then:

```
class A : public myMethodWrapper<int, int>, 
          public myMethodWrapper<float, float>
{
};
```

That behaves similarly.

Comment: I thought of this too but I wasn't sure if the identically named functions from each base would combine properly.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes, that actually went better than I thought - I didn't know if one would shadow the other, but to get the error you did they both had to be considered.

Comment: Just make explicit which one you intend to call `a.myMethod<int,int>(0, 0);`. If the parameters are different enough that won't even be necessary.

Comment: interesting solution, though if I need to have 25 methods, looking strange to inherit class from 25 base classes :) but it works..

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to put the template code outside the class and call it from class methods.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

namespace myTemplates
{
  // template method 'mult(a,b)'
  // returns a*b
  template <class T1, class T2>
    T1 mult(T1 a, T2 b)
    {
      T1 result = a * b;
      return result;
    }

  // template specialization 'mult(string aString, int m)'
  // returns a string repeated m times
  template <>
    string mult<string, int>(string input, int m)
    {
      string result;
      for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
      {
        result += input;
      }
      return result;
    }
}

class A {
  public:
    A(){}
    int    mult(int    a , int   b ) { return myTemplates::mult(a, b ) ; }
    float  mult(float  a , float b ) { return myTemplates::mult(a, b ) ; }
    string mult(string a , int   b ) { return myTemplates::mult(a, b ) ; }
};

int main(void)
{
  int    iA = 2;
  int    iB = 3;
  int    iC = 0;   // result
  float  fA = 20.1;
  float  fB = 30.3;
  float  fC = 0.0; // result
  string sA = " -blah- ";
  string sC;       // result


  iC = myTemplates::mult(iA,iB);
  cout << "mult(" << iA << ", " << iB << ") = " << iC << endl;

  fC = myTemplates::mult(fA,fB);
  cout << "mult(" << fA << ", " << fB << ") = " << fC << endl;

  sC = myTemplates::mult(sA,iB); 
  cout << "mult(" << sA << ", " << iB << ") = " << sC << endl;

  A a; 

  iC = a.mult(iA,iB);
  cout << "a.mult(" << iA << ", " << iB << ") = " << iC << endl;

  fC = a.mult(fA,fB);
  cout << "a.mult(" << fA << ", " << fB << ") = " << fC << endl;

  sC = a.mult(sA,iB);
  cout << "a.mult(" << sA << ", " << iB << ") = " << sC << endl;

  return 1;
}
```

output:

```
  mult(2, 3) = 6
  mult(20.1, 30.3) = 609.03
  mult( -blah- , 3) =  -blah-  -blah-  -blah-
  a.mult(2, 3) = 6
  a.mult(20.1, 30.3) = 609.03
  a.mult( -blah- , 3) =  -blah-  -blah-  -blah-
```