# Template functions in C++? Maybe not the correct term

Tags: c++, function, templates, declaration

I am not sure if I am using the right term but I am curious if there is a more efficient way of doing things. I have a file loader that deals with numerous fragments (about 30 in total). My class it littered with:

```
void fragment_03(char* location, int frag_num);
void fragment_04(char* location, int frag_num);
void fragment_05(char* location, int frag_num);
void fragment_06(char* location, int frag_num);
```

...and so forth. Is there a way better way to declare these functions in a more generic way rather than writing out 30 different function declarations?

Thanks!

Comment: depends on what those functions do.. Are they doing similar work, or are they entirely different from each other? One point of confusion for me is that I would expected "`fragment_03`" to be called for the 3rd "fragment" of the file, but you pass `frag_num` also... so perhaps not? If not, perhaps a better name would do? Either way, give us some examples of what these functions look like and we can give you a good solution :-).

Comment: You might actually want to review the design that lead you to having 30 different functions with basically the same name and arguments... I would suggest renaming

Comment: @EvanTeran They do very different things. I was just curious if there was a way to declare all of them based on something like fragment_x -  if this makes no sense. I apologize.

Comment: If they do "very different things", why are they named all the same?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8578966/is-it-possible-to-declare-methods-via-template-in-c That was my question - may be you will find the answer on yours

Comment: How are they related?  Are they called in sequence for each incoming block?  Templates might be useful in that case.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure if this is what you want to do, but:

You will have to declare and define all of your functions separately, but you can store your function pointers in an array.

```
typedef void (fragment_function) (char* location, int frag_num);

frag_function fragment_0, fragment_1, fragment_2; //define functions in cpp file

fragment_function *fragment [] =
{
    fragment_0,
    fragment_1,
    fragment_2
};
```

Then define them like this:

```
void fragment_0(char* location, int frag_num) { /**your definition here*/ }
```

So that they can be called by index like this:

```
for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
{
    fragment[i](frag_location[i], frag_num[i]);
}
```

Comment: You can also make a typedef for a function type (not only function pointer) and that will make declaring many identical functions easier.  Doesn't help with the definitions though.

Answer (score 0):

Functions with different names and same signatures can be called using function pointers. Or else you can choose to have templated functions and specialized template functions.